# "General purpose" current limiter?

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, current, current-limiting, variable

I have been trying for a few weeks to create a current limiter that fills my needs but I have failed.  Idon't even know if it's possible. Basically I want to make a current limiter that can work with many different applications. In this case linear power supplies. I want a current limiter that follows:

**Adjustable 10mA - 3A**

**Easily customizable, i.e if i want to change the limiter from maybe 10mA to 1A or 1mA to 500mA etc.**

**I want the current to go through a NPN power transistor.**

Is there a circuit available that can do all this? I have tried to simulate a few with a lot of googling but i have not found one yet.

I recently started reading about op-amps and tried to make a limiter using that. But I didn't really know where to begin.

Any tips on how to build this is appreciated!

Comment: Have you searched "current limiting power supply schematic"? Because the first several results I looked through look exactly like what you are asking for...

Comment: @Tyler now i feel very stupid.. i googled exactly that and found this: http://fritzing.org/media/fritzing-repo/projects/h/hotwire-foam-cutter/other_files/external%20current%20limiting%20circuit.pdf

Which seems to show exactly what i needed.. Thank you!

Comment: and btw, i just simulated some of those circuits. and i don't really know what to modify to make the limiter go down to 10 mA but still provide up to 3A current.. tips?

Comment: @Xane: I think it's time to give up on all your LM317 power supplies you've been working on over the past few months and build a decent and efficient bench power supply. Ideally choose a design that allows you to set both voltage and current limit before you switch the output on. ;^)

Comment: @transistor: LT has a nice one with a switch mode pre-regulator and linear post regulation with cc and cv mode settings. It should not be difficult to add sensing and a display for Vo and Io limits :) http://www.linear.com/docs/45095

Comment: @PeterSmith: Very nice. Pricey at $200 from Linear. I wonder if someone else has copied it. See [EEVBlog Forum](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/linear-technology-dc2132a-cvcc-adj-bench-power-supply-board/) for discussion on it. I like the SMPS pre-regulator. Xane, I was using the LM317 almost 40 years ago. They still work but technology has improved!

Comment: @transistor , so what do you propose (as technology improved), any specific IC or topology , etc ...?

Comment: I'm proposing that Xane does some new research. I've been helping her/him out with LM317 circuits for a while. Peter has given a good starting point. The Linear kit is expensive but that's deliberate as explained in the EEVBlog link and the board design is probably public so there should be far cheaper clones.

Comment: @transistor, i have kind of given up with the whole LM317 idea. because no matter how i do it, I never get it setup the way i want it. That is why i wondered about a current limiter without any regulator. Once i have a current limiter ready i can get to work on a voltage regulator without any "simple" IC hehe

Comment: @Xane: Arrrrrrrrgh! Stop! Integrate the voltage and current control into one device. Use SMPS to reduce losses and eliminate most of your heatsinking. You won't regret it. A decent bench PSU is an essential piece of kit.

Comment: The reason why i only speak of linear supplies, is that SMPS are too advanced for me. Except for those IC.s like LM2678 etc.

Answer (score 4):

I give you a simple idea of universal current limiter with this circuit:

[image]

You can get curent limitter by adjusting the potentiometer of 5k, and you can modify the 0.5Ω resistor to get a different value of current limitation.

Be careful: R=0.5Ω is a 10W power risistor like this one:

[image]

The input voltage can be from 12V to 50V, but at the maximum voltage you may need a heat sink on the power transistor 2N3055.

Comment: I just tried to simulate this and it worked pretty well except that the current won't go lower than 400 mA, do you have any idea what i need to change to make it go lower?

Comment: Good, you can change the resistor of 0.5Ω to 1Ω or 2Ω to get a current less then 1A