# 22V 2A current limiter circuit

Tags: power-supply, current-limiting, constant-current

I need to build a simple circuit to limit the current of a 22-25V input (from two car batteries) to 2 amperes - to avoid frying a battery charging circuit.

I found this one - ["General Purpose" Current Limiter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247783/general-purpose-current-limiter) which looks like it should do the job (though I was hoping from something MOSFET based).

I'm not sure on the calculations, however - i.e. to work out the values to fix at 2 amperes.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Do you really need to limit the current?  Most devices have a rated voltage and a rated current.  If you give them the rated voltage, then they will consume only the rated current - no external current limiting is needed.  Post a link to the charger, and let us see if you really need what you think you need.

Comment: What battery charging circuit do you have?

Comment: Hi @Parker - the LiPo side of the circuit is based around isl94202 which looks after the  CFET and DFETs and well as the balancing. This is all working as expected - connected to bench PSU at the moment. The bench PSU has a current limit (limited to 2A) - which is the functional I want to replicate.

Comment: So that is a battery monitor/balancing circuit. What you need is a charging circuit . https://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/charger-ics/products.html

Comment: https://instantpanel.co.nz/products/constant-current-and-voltage-module-5a-adjustable

Comment: Hi @BruceAbbott - many thanks that is just what I need.